# Is it possible to pass local memory of std::vector element to a function?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management

My code can be found at [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f123a81534d0db2). Important fragments are the following:

```
int main(){
    //create some random data
    std::vector<data_type> data(10000);
    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), data_filler<data_type>());

    std::vector< DataBucket<data_type> > data_buckets(19);
    // distribute the data into DataBuckets
    for(auto& data_point : data){
    // non-sense condition to sort data into buckets for this 
    // example to show the bucket a data point falls into isn't known a priori
        data_buckets[rand()%data_buckets.size()].AddData(data_point);
    }
}
```

My template class `DataBucket` is:

```
template<typename T = float>
class DataBucket {
public:
    DataBucket() {};
    ~DataBucket(){};
    inline void AddData(const T& data){
        this->data.emplace_back(data);
    };
    inline const std::vector<T>& Data() const {
        return this->data;
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

The code is pretty simple, basically only a few data points `std::vector<data_type> data(100)` are assigned into `DataBucket` which hold a private `std::vector<T> data` to store the data.

I'm wondering if the local memory of variable `data` in main could be assigned to the `std::vector<T> data` directly without copying again. Since I won't use the `data` vector not any further in main after the data got assigned to the buckets. Since the data is already allocated it would make sense to not allocate the entire data again, but rather just shift if to another owner. A `DataBucket` object should be the only owner of the assigned data.

I'm quite new to c++ so I might have overseen some features, but right now can't figure out any better way than my example code given above.

Comment: The short answer is: "no". To do this, use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`, instead, for your `data` vector. Ditto for the template class member, and just assign the smart pointer. You can read the chapter in your C++ book that talks about smart pointers, for more information.

Comment: You could move the vector from main to something, but not multiple times. You might want an `array_view` of some kind.

Comment: have you considered a move semantic ?

Comment: Whether move semantics helps or not depends on what data_type looks like. If it contains dynamically allocated data then it would help otherwise it needs to be tested.

Comment: You need move semantics but you're not ready for them at this stage. The basic idea is simple - move a pointer when you can instead of copying a whole buffer - but the implementation is complex and confusing to someone just starting out on C++.